# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::update() even though the method is definitely defined

Tags: php

I'm getting

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::update()in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/gallery/admin/includes/content.php:14
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/gallery/admin/index.php(11):
>   require_once() #1 {main} thrown in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/gallery/admin/includes/content.php
>   on line 14.

However, the method `update()` is defined. Here is the user class:

```
class User {
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;

    public static function find_query($query) {
        global $db;

        $obj_arr = NULL;

        if($db -> query($query) -> num_rows != 1) {
            $users = $db -> query($query);

            while($user = $users -> fetch_object()) {
                $obj_arr[] = $user; 
            }

            return $obj_arr;
        } else {
            return $db -> query($query) -> fetch_object();
        }
    }

    public static function find_all() {
        return self::find_query("SELECT * FROM users");
    }

    public static function get_user_byId($id) {
        return self::find_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1");
    }

    public static function verify_user($username, $password) {
        global $db;

        $username = $db -> escape_string($username);
        $password = $db -> escape_string($password);

        $q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";

        return self::find_query($q);
    }

    public function create() {
        global $db;

        $username = $db -> escape_string($this -> username);
        $password = $db -> escape_string($this -> password);
        $first_name = $db -> escape_string($this -> first_name);
        $last_name = $db -> escape_string($this -> last_name);

        $q = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, first_name, last_name) ";
        $q .= "VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$first_name', '$last_name')";

        if($db -> query($q)) {
            $this -> id = $db -> insert_id();

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function update() {
        global $db;

        $id = (int) $id;

        $username = $db -> escape_string($this -> username);
        $password = $db -> escape_string($this -> password);
        $first_name = $db -> escape_string($this -> first_name);
        $last_name = $db -> escape_string($this -> last_name);

        $q = "UPDATE users SET username='$username', password='$password', first_name='$first_name', last_name='$last_name' ";
        $q .= "WHERE id=$id";

        //return (mysqli_affected_rows($db -> db) == 1) ? true:false;
        return ($db -> db -> affected_rows == 1) ? true:false;
    }
}
```

I have called update like so:

```
$user = User::get_user_byId(4);
$user -> password = 'newpass';
$user -> update();
```

The other methods work fine, just `update()`. Is this an instantiation problem perhaps? I'm so sorry if this is a stupid question. I have looked on here for answers but can't find anything relevant enough to solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: `return $db -> query($query) -> fetch_object();` returns a `Standard Class` object, not a `User` object

Comment: If you want to return a specific object type, look at the arguments for [fetch_object()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php)

Comment: Ah... how do I make it return a User Class then? I'm new to OOP.

Comment: If you want to return a specific object type, look at the arguments for [fetch_object()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php)

Comment: Oh that's simple... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
return $db -> query($query) -> fetch_object("User");
```

[`fetch_object()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) by default returns a `Standard Class` (`stdClass`) object. That's why you're getting a `Call to undefined method stdClass::update()`. You can provide the desired Class name by passing its name in the first argument of the function.

Comment: Yeah I got that now. Thanks (: By the way @mark, I'm marking this as the answer and I can't mark your comment. Thanks though

Answer (score -2):

> User::get_user_byId

gives you not an instance of the class User. So $user don't have any methods of Class User.

You have to make an instance of the Class User like

> $user = new User();

an than you can use the Methods like

> $user->update();